# HTML/CSS - Adjust font-size when going between desktop and mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile, font-size

I have this simple html file and I am trying to understand why my font size doesn't scale down when I move to mobile view. I though `font-size:7em` would adjust when moving from desktop to mobile.

I know this is super silly, but I can't understand. Do I need to use a `@media query`?

> `

```css
body {
    background: black;
    font-family: "Big Caslon";
    margin-top:3em;
    margin-bottom:3vw;
    margin-left:12vw;
    margin-right:12vw;
  }

section {
    color: white;
    padding: 1em;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-right: -50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
  }

.title {
  font-size:7em;
  margin:10px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>

    <title>ShopDoran</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="doran.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">


</head>

  <section>
    <div class="title">  D O R A N  </div>
    <p style="font-size:2em; margin:10px;">coming soon </p>
  </section>

</html>
```

`

Comment: you need to take a look at [CSS units](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp) to understand how each are working, and media query would do what you expect in your case for sure

Comment: `em` is relative to the font-size of the element (7em means 7 times the size of the current font), so `font-size:7em` may be a recursive definition. Do you mean `rem`? And `vw` and `vh` may also be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First up you need to make sure you [understand the different values css offer us](https://youtu.be/N5wpD9Ov_To) so you can get a better idea of when to use each one.

The correct way to solve this would be for you to [set up a @media query](https://youtu.be/2KL-z9A56SQ) in your css file so it can change its values depending on the size of the screen, in this case 600px or smaller.
I would also recommend using rem instead of em's, as nesting em's might not always workout as you expect if you don't fully understand [how it works](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_-aDOAMmDHI), as for rem it is always based on the root font size so [it's more predictable](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pautqDqa54I),

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .title {
    font-size: 2rem;

  }
```

A more modern approach and a bit easier but sometimes chaotic would be to approach the [`font-size:` with vw values](https://youtu.be/IWFqGsXxJ1E?t=458) which takes the viewport width as a value and depending on the amount of screen space the font will grow, this is not always recommended as text can get to big so you need to limit the max size for things not to get to crazy which you can do with the `clamp:()` function which is [a more reliable way of using vw units in `font-size:`](https://youtu.be/U9VF-4euyRo?t=815) and keeping everything under control, you would end with something like this:

```
.title{font-size: clamp(2rem, 5vw+1rem, 7rem);}
```

Answer (score 0):

hi @giaggi do use the unit '''font-size:7vw''' for the font size it should fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check the CSS Unit as @Burham B. Soliman mentioned, But I will draw a guideline on how you can make it:

1- Add Font size into your HTML body like this:

```
html{
  font-size:16px;
}
```

2- Size the element font like this:

```
title{
  font-size: 3rem;
}
```

3- Set A Media Query for desire viewport size (for example 600px):

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  html{
    font-size: 10px;
  }
}
```

There are also other ways that you can handle this. It is just an example.